# What really is an element and set?

Tags: set-theory

The definition of a subset $E\subset X$ means that if $x\in E$, then $x\in X$ also.

Then, is $\{0,1,…,n-1\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$? Obviously it looks like it is, but suppose I construct the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and I label its elements $\{0,1,…,n-1\}$. Then is $\{0,1,…,n-1\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$? Each element represents a coset and not an integer, but in this form the cosets (literally) look like integers. Instead of looking at the elements' bare appearances, should I instead consider their “behavior” to identity them?

But this approach also feels problematic. If I create an “isomorphic” copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\{…,a_{-1},a_0,a_1,…\}$ (with the elements behaving as you’d expect), then we would have $a_{58}\in\mathbb{Z}$, which seems morally incorrect. I could use a more obscure representation of $\mathbb{Z}$ to say that two objects that look like a matrix and topological group reside in the same "subset" of $\mathbb{Z}$.

How do I keep track of elements to know whether they are contained in a set or not? I mentioned two “methods”, either to look at their literal appearance or their “behavior” (which isn’t even well-defined), but both lead to unappealing conclusions. I’d be happy to hear of any texts that address this issue, or if there is a conclusive way to identity objects.

Comment: I have two gut reactions: (1) is it possible you are conflating names of elements with elements? (2) Every time it looks like you have a subset you should hopefully have a function whose image is a subset so it's not that far off? (3) I think the problem is you're asking deep questions without proper formal definitions and techniques. For what it's worth I don't like touching this stuff, but I know my limits!

Comment: The answer is to look at literal appearance, but you need to look at an actual set-theoretic construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ in order to see that appearance.  For example, one popular approach is to first use $\omega$ (a specific set) to represent the non-negative integers, and use an equivalence class of ordered pairs (n,m) such that $n \in \omega$ and $m \in \omega$  to represent the integer $(n - m)$.  Specifically, if $k = (n - m)$, and $n \in \omega$ and $m \in \omega$, then the ordered pair (n,m) is an element of the equivalence class that represents the integer value k.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to your concerns divides in three parts.

**I**

I see what you mean but the idea is this.

"$A \subset B$" is a logical proposition, that means it is either true or false.

So, if I write for example

"Let $A = \{a_1,a_2...,a_n\}$ such that $A \subset \mathbb{Z}.$"

In this last sentence I am saying that  $\{a_1,a_2...,a_n\} = A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is true, you don't have to worry about wether an $a_i$ is not an integer. I am already telling you that they are integers, regardless of how weird those $a_i$ may look for every $i \in \{1,...,n\}$.

**II**

Yes, there could be many ways we could confuse our readers by saying things like:

"Let $\{1,...,n-1\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}" \quad (*)$

in this particular case, this means that "$\{1,...,n-1\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$" is a false proposition!, or in other words, $"\{1,...,n-1\} \nsubseteq \mathbb{Z}$" is a true proposition!

We must certainly avoid that kind of ambiguity, so the general agreement is that if we write $\{1,...,n\}$ we are talking of those integers, in other words, we don't label arbitrary elements of an arbitrary set as numbers, so $(*)$ it's not a correct way to write math.

The way to do it is to use a distinguisher with the number, for example,

"Let $\{\overline{1},...,\overline{n-1}\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$".

in this case it is clear that we are talking about the quotients and not the numbers, you could use also $\{[1],...,[n-1]\}$.

**III**

Lastly, some times you do indeed have to abuse some notation, but there is a justification for that. For example, you may encounter the following sentence:

"Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d \end{pmatrix}$ be a $2 \times 2$ **matrix** of real numbers, and let $(x,y)$ be a **vector** in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we observe that:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = (ax+by, cx+dy)". \quad (**)$$

This last proposition may raise a lot of concerns because: 1. you are multiplying a matrix with a vector (and multiplication should be all matrices!) and 2. and you are getting a vector as a result (and the result should be a matrix!). However, this proposition abuses the fact that the vector space of matrices with one row and two columns with real entries (that is: $M_{1 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$), the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the vector  space of matrices with two rows and one column with real entries (that is: $M_{2 \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$) are all isomorphic, that is:

$$M_{1 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \cong M_{2 \times 1}(\mathbb{R}),$$

so, in this context we may treat $(x \, y) \in M_{1 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ as the same as $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and this last as the same as $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} M_{2 \times 1}$. This justifies the abuse of terms in $(**)$, and you will encounter many examples and theory that use this type of resource.

**Edit.**

Another case we can see abuse of notation is when someone says "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$", *strictly speaking* it is false that "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$" since the left set has elements of the form $m + n\mathbb{Z} := \{m + nk \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and the right set is just integers, **however** it's ok to write "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$" because $\mathbb{Z}$ *contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$* in it, that isomorphic set is $\{1,...,n\}$, more formally:

**Proposition.** Let $N = \{1,...,n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, then there is a bijection between $N$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$

For the proof we consider

$$\begin{matrix} \phi : & \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} & \rightarrow & \{1,...,n\} \\  
 & m + nk & \mapsto & m
\end{matrix} $$

this is a biyection (it has inverse given by $m \mapsto m + nk \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

So "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$" is an abuse of notation but it is justified because there is $N = \{1,...,n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $N \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. So, when one author says "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$", what he means is that "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong N \subset \mathbb{Z}$".

Comment: But why is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}$ false?

Comment: @SamuelHan I edited my question, check it out.

Comment: With this argument, doesn’t any set $A$ with cardinality less than another set $B$ become a subset of $B$?

Comment: @SamuelHan yes, you can do that, but we usually abuse  the notation $A \subset B$ when there is an algebraic structure behind that is preserved, in this case $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring.

Comment: I know that there exist maps that preserve structure, but in the setting of sets, how does an embedding (of sets) preserve structure of an element? In particular, for your example, a coset doesn't have to be mapped to its representative for the map to be bijective.

Comment: As a more explicit example, should the set $E$ of square numbers $n^2$ be considered a subset of the naturals? $E$ isn't closed under addition the way $\mathbb{N}$ is. Of course, $E$ is closed under multiplication like $\mathbb{N}$, but why should we be allowed to "cherry-pick" which algebraic property is "relevant" and which one isn't?

Comment: The set of square numbers $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, because $m$ is a squared number if and only if there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^2 = m$, so you can show that $E \subset \mathbb{N}$ using the definition you mentioned in your question. Let $x \in E$, by definition $x = n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x \in \mathbb{N}$ which proves that indeed $E \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I should've properly defined $E$ as a construction from $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring, so that each element of $E$ is the square of an element in $\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm sorry. However, I don't know if I can define $n^2$ for $\mathbb{N}$ as a set - wouldn't that imply that $\mathbb{N}$ is something more than a set and has some structure? I'm now wondering if I should close this current question and instead ask whether the notion of a structure lies in a set or its elements.